# Влияние невидимых элементов на скорость загрузки веб-страницы

Tags: html, вёрстка

Допустим у нас насыщенная разными элементами веб-страница, при этом большинство элементов - скрыты (`display: none;`) и показываются только при их вызове через JavaScript. Насколько эти скрытые элементы окажут влияние на скорость загрузки страницы?

Comment: Капитан Очевидность докладывает, что передача кода элементов по интернету и их парсинг браузером занимает время. А какое время - фиг знает, никакой конкретной информации в вопросе ведь нету

Comment: @andreymal Парсинг одного только HTML едва ли займёт много времени. Другое дело - CSS. Я правильно понял, что применеие CSS занимает времени в равной степени для видимых и невидимых элементов?

Comment: В Хром можно поставить модуль расширения "Page load time" и протестировать страницу, в результаты вы будете точно знать как влияют скрытые элементы и можете попытаться даже соптимизировать, если надо.

Answer (score 0):

Влияние на скорость страницы по сравнению с чем?
Если без них - то явно скорость будет выше. А если эти же елементы Вы куда-то планируете засунуть и тоже подгружать на странице, то тут надо тестировать.

Например, вы можете все такие элементы вынести в js файл и загружать вместе со страницей, при этом сохраняя в кеш-браузера эти js-файлы, и в следующий раз страница будет загружаться у пользователя быстрее чем в первый раз, и быстрее чем, если бы эти элементы были написаны со свойством display сразу на странице.